# Why this not working in JS?? getElementById().style.width += 40 + "px";

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to write a shorthand method getElementById().style.width += 40 + "px"; for changing element width in DOM via JavasScript but it isn't working.
Any working solutions to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

if `document.getElementById(id).style.width` returns `"10px"`
then `document.getElementById(id).style.width += 40 + "px"` will be
`"10px40px"`

Comment: In short, change `+=` to `=`

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest—not in the intention is to increment by 40px, which is inferred by `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

Shorthand assignment is not possible. but you should try the following:

```
document.getElementById("div1").style.width = (parseInt(document.getElementById("div1").style.width) + 40) + "px";
```

Note: replace [id] with an appropriate id.

Full example code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function incrementWidth() {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.width = (parseInt(document.getElementById("div1").style.width) + 40) + "px";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1" style="height:100px;width:40px;background-color:orange;"></div>
  <button onclick="incrementWidth();">INCREMENT</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put your full code, i will check and let you know.

Comment: This does not work because you're trying to parse "10px", which cannot be parsed to an integer.

Comment: Actually at my knowledge if we parse string and string has integers then parseint will extract integer portion. So i have used it.

Comment: Ah, you're right. My mistake; It will still parse it unless the first character is a string.

Comment: K buddy. Have a great day.